# angular 4.3x dynamic http interceptor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I followed [this article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) from medium to create a http interceptor which lets me add headers to each http call

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

The article uses the authService to get a token dynamically. However as soon as I inject HttpClient into the AuthService I get a circular injection error.

Are there other ways i can dynamically adjust the interceptor?

Comment: can you share your service code from where you are initiating a request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A conventional way to avoid circular dependencies in both AngularJS and Angular is to get another provider instance in-place and not on provider instantiation:

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public injector: Injector) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const httpClient = injector.get(HttpClient);
    ...
  }
}
```

Notice that if the interceptor applies to all `HttpClient` requests, it will be applied to the one that is done inside the interceptor itself and likely result in infinite recursion. In order to avoid this the request can be marked to skip the interceptor (e.g. via custom header).

Comment: Using Injector is really helpful in such situations. Imagine that you have TranslateService which depends on HttpClient & HttpInterceptor (which are used to load translations from JSON), and interceptor on itself depends on Translation Service to send locale parameter in requests. You get a loop.

Answer (score -3):

From the [article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) it says:

> It should be noted that Angular’s new HttpClient from
>   @angular/common/http is being used here and not the Http class from
>   @angular/http. **If we try to make requests with the traditional
>   Httpclass, the interceptor won’t be hit**

Please make sure you are using `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` in the import section.

and then it the constructor use it: `constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}`