# Injection via the constructor parameters vs. the Injector service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am using Angular2/4 for few months now and I still cannot figure out what is the difference between these two methods and which one I should use about Dependency Injection

Can you help me please.

### First method : via the constructor

```
...
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) { 
    // this.myService.myMethod() ...
  }
...
```

and

### Second Method : via the Injector

```
...
  private myService: MyService;

  constructor(
    injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.myService = injector.get(MyService);
    // this.myService.myMethod() ...
  }
...
```

I understand what is done in each method, bubt I cannot figure out the best practice.

I know it is probably a subjective opinion, but I think there pros and cons for both of them.

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: Your second method has *both*; the injector is provided via constructor injection. Also note that the docs tell you: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#appendix-working-with-injectors-directly

Comment: I am not expert in DI but in the first method, when we create the `component`  instance angular look for the dependencies which is required for `this` component, by typechecking the `constructor` parameters. which is good for many cases, but in second method you inject whole `DI Container` which include all sevices,but not required in all cases. please check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/architecture#dependency-injection)

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Thx, your link was helpful.

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan : Thanks, I am not sure it makes a real difference, as everything is passed by reference, no ? But I think you are right: first method is better ... simply because, watching constructor, you can quickly tell which dependencies are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always prefer the first option:

```
...
  constructor(
    private myService: MyService
  ) { 
    // this.myService.myMethod() ...
  }
...
```

The second approach works because when you inject `MyService` it is injected using the `Injector`.

Angular makes `Injector` available for injection because you may need to use it when dynamically instantiating modules or components:

Component:

```
export class ModuleLoaderComponent {
  constructor(private _injector: Injector,private loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader) { ... }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.loader.load('app/t.module#TModule').then((factory) => {
      const module = factory.create(this._injector);  <-----------------
```

Module:

```
export class RouterConfigLoader {

  load(parentInjector, route) {
    ...
    const modFactory = this.loadModuleFactory(route.loadChildren);
    const module = modFactory.create(parentInjector);
  }
```

You can read more about dynamic instantiation in the following articles:

- [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)
- [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e)

As @estus noted, `injector` is also used in cases where injecting a dependency in a constructor results in circular dependency or you want to get dependency depending on some conditions.

Comment: It should be also noticed that `injector` is used in cases where injecting a dep in constructor results in circular dependency.

Comment: Something like that, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46470684/3731501 . Also useful for getting a dep dynamically based on some condition.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com , for performance perpective , always first approach is good right, becoz inject the `Injector` will leads to create all services which is not required by `current component`, correct me if i am wrong?

Comment: @estus OK, but Circular Dependencies are proof of bad project structuration, no ?

Comment: @M'sieurToph' It depends. This may be true if all of the dependencies were defined by a user and result in A->B->A dep graph. Circular dep is natural when it is imposed by framework design and is expected.

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan  `Injector will leads to create all services which is not required by current component` nope, it won't create all services. Angular will just  create new instance-wrapper of Injector for view https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L388-L389 https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/refs.ts#L326

Answer (score 1):

I've been told that it is often better to use the constructor method for dependency injection. It tells you exactly what this class needs.

On the other hand, there are cases where you are better off using the injector. Along with dynamic instantiation, you also have to consider class inheritance Suppose that you want to build a component off of a base component that brings in services S2 that is also based on other services S1. that is C2(S2) from C1(S1).

Normally, C2 instantiates C1 using the super, which looks something like this

```
constructor(
    private service2: S2
  ) { 
    super(S1)
  }
```

I see a problem with having to call the parent service S1 and S2 in order to build C2. It gets less tangled if S1 uses the injector method so that writing C2 is as simple as

```
constructor(
    private injector: Injector
  ) { 
    super()
    this.service2 = this.injector.get(S2)
  }

private service2: S2
```

You can go further and create your own injector singleton if want to forgo setting instance in the constructor. See 
[this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-inheritance-without-effort-8200c8d87972)

Comment: Needing `Injector` for this isn't necessary anymore as of Angular v14, I shared an answer about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74148857/1917171