# cyclic dependency. HttpInterceptor and TranslateService

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-translate, angular-http-interceptors, cyclic-dependency

This is discussed a lot, but I can't find how to solve my issue.

The reason is clear, I'm trying to use translateService in my interceptor, but both depends on httpClient.

I only happens when my interceptor constructor is:

```
  constructor(    
    private router: Router,
    private translate: TranslateService){}
```

If I remove translate it doesn't fails because of cyclic dependency.

So, I guess I need to access to translate in some different way but I can't find it.

How can I do it?

I tried the links suggestions, finally I got it.

```
constructor(    
private router: Router,
private injector: Injector){
  const translate =  injector.get(TranslateService);
}


intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     //intercept method and:
   .catch(err => this.handleError(err));

}


private handleError(error): Observable<any> {

if (error.status === 401) {
  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
} else if (error.status === 403) {
  this.router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
} else {
   this.injector.get(TranslateService).get(['GENERIC_ERROR', 'OK'])
}
return Observable.throw(error);
```

}

Comment: provide TranslateService under providers in NgModule

Comment: Please, update the question with how exactly you use the service there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 4.3x dynamic http interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46470469/angular-4-3x-dynamic-http-interceptor)

Comment: to avoid circular dependency try use injector, see, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482460/getting-instance-of-service-without-constructor-injection but you can re-think your code.

Comment: edit with suggestions