# NGX Translate inside Library throws Circular Dependency error when used in HTTP_INTERCEPTOR

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a angular library where I created a `LanguageModule`  defined as follows

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
          deps: [HttpClient]
        },
      })
    ],
    exports: [TranslateModule]
  })
  export class LanguageModule {
    public constructor(translateSvc: TranslateService, http: HttpClient) {
      translateSvc.onLangChange
        .pipe(
          switchMap((currentLang: LangChangeEvent) => zip(
            of(currentLang),
            http.get(`assets/i18n/${currentLang.lang}.json`),
          ))
        ).subscribe(([currentLang, localizations, syncfusionLocalization]) => {
          translateSvc.setTranslation(translateSvc.currentLang, localizations, true);
          setCulture(currentLang.lang);
        });
  
      translateSvc.use(translateSvc.getDefaultLang());
    }
  }
```

This allows me to merge library and app localization files.

Inside my app I import the `LanguageModule`  in the main `app.module.ts`, where I also import my `CoreModule`, defined as follows:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ...
    ],
    declarations: [],
    providers: [
        ....
      // Http interceptors
      {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthInterceptor,
        multi: true
      }
    ]
  })
  export class CoreModule {  
    public constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
      if (parentModule) {
        throw new Error('CoreModule has already been loaded. Import CoreModule in the AppModule only.');
      }
    }  
  }
```

In the `AuthInterceptor`, if I inject the `TranslateService`  I get the following error:
*`Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS.`*

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide a stackblitz? I would like to what your AuthInterceptor have. I did also had created a library for my ngx-translate, but realized that the `TranslateModule.forRoot({})` still had to be instantiated in the project that does import the library.  Also usefull if you wants to merge multiple i18n files together. _the one from your library and the one from you local project_

Comment: normally you can solve a Circular dependency using `injector` or moving the components to diferents Module, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152273/angular-circular-dependency-when-inject-translateservice-to-interceptor (It's looks like your problem)

Comment: @Eliseo I have tried with the injector but still get the same error. In this case I cannot move the interceptor to another module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After losing my mind it seems someone on github found a solution, by removing defaultLanguage from the TranslateModule.forRoot() in AppModule.
https://github.com/gilsdav/ngx-translate-router/issues/94#issuecomment-791584329

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29943776)

Comment: This works! No clue why to be honest, but it does!

Answer (score 2):

Your `TranslateService` depends on `HttpClient`, `HttpClient` depends on `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` which include `AuthInterceptor`.

So when you add `TranslateService` as a dependency for `AuthInterceptor` you get a full circle: `TranslateService` => `TranslateLoader` => `HttpClient` => `AuthInterceptor` => `TranslateService`.

There is an official guide here https://angular.io/errors/NG0200

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Could you elaborate on what a potential solution would look like?

Comment: actually taking a look at the ngx-translate service source, it does not depend on HttpClient

Comment: @AaronUllal, it depends on TranslateLoader which depends on HttpClient, I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense. How would you go about to solve this CD? I've tried using the injector to get the translateService but I still get the same error

Comment: @AaronUllal Did you find any solution?

Comment: @SaghiShiri sadly, no

Answer (score 0):

Just solved the problem by removing the HttpClient Dependency and making the Translate i18n request using fetch().

```
getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        const url = `${environment.i18nURL}/${lang}.json?ts=${timestamp}`;
        return from(fetch(url).then((el: any) => el.json()));
}

export function CustomLoaderFactory() {
    return new CustomTranslateLoader();
}

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        defaultLanguage: environment.defaultLanguage,
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: CustomLoaderFactory,
            deps: [], // Removed => HttpClient
        },
    }),
],
...
```